# Verilog always block with no sensitivity list

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

would an `always` block with no sensitivity list infer a combinational logic, just the same as `always_comb` or `always @(*)`? Eg code:

```
always begin
if (sig_a)begin
 @(posedge sig_b); // wait for a sig_b posedge event
 @(negedge sig_b); // then wait for a sig_b negedge event
 event_true=1;  
end

if (event_true)begin
  @((sig_c==1)&&(sig_a==0)); //wait for sig_a to deassert and sig_c assert event to be true
  yes =1;
 end
 else yes =0;

end
```

Comment: there is **no** combinatorial logic in your example, and it is not synthesizable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synthesis tools require a specific template coding style to synthesize your code. Most only allow a single explicit event control ar the beginning of an `always` block. Some of the higher-level synthesis tools that do allow multiple event controls only allow multiple occurrences of the same clock edge.

Simulation tools don't have these restrictions and will try to execute whatever legal syntax you can compile. BTW, your `@((sig_c==1)&&(sig_a==0))` means wait for the expression to change value, not wait for it to become true. The `wait(expr)`construct means wait for the expression to become true.

Comment: Thanks Dave ... but how would a `always begin <some code>  end` without a sensitivity list know at which events to trigger , or will this just infer a combi logic kinda like `always @(*)` or `always_comb` does?

Comment: For combinatorial logic, you must provide a sensitivity list. You do this explicitly using `always` or implicitly using `always @*` or always_comb`

Answer (score -1):

I tried it in Quartus, and both of these do result in the same realization after synthesis.

```
always x = counter[0] + counter[1];

assign y = counter[0] + counter[1];
```

I do not know how prevalent the support for this is.